# How to Drop rows in DataFrame by conditions on column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I  created code to drop some rows according to certain condition :

```
df3 = df_clean[(df_clean['group'] == 'treatment') & (df_clean['landing_page'] != 'new_page')].index
df2 = df_clean.drop(df3 , inplace=True)
df2.head()
```

but I got this error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'head'

Comment: you dont need to give .index. The condition itself will take care of it. df3 itself is the answer you need

Comment: When you use `inplace`, an object won't be returned, so `df2` doesn't exist.  Try `df_clean.drop(df3 , inplace=True)`, but don't try to set it to a variable, then try `df3.head()` for the last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign ***df_clean*** to ***df2*** without the inplace

```
 df2 = df_clean.drop(df3)
```

Or leave the inplace without assigning, here ***df_clean*** will be your output

```
 df_clean.drop(df3 , inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. I dont have your dataset so using my own.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800],
                   'B':['apple','banana','apple','banana',
                        'apple','banana','apple','banana']})

print (df)
df1 = df[(df['A'] >400) & (df['B'] == 'apple')]
print (df1)
```

If I want to get all the rows with 'apple' and values > 400, then, df1 will give me the result.

```
     A       B
0  100   apple
1  200  banana
2  300   apple
3  400  banana
4  500   apple
5  600  banana
6  700   apple
7  800  banana
     A      B
4  500  apple
6  700  apple
```